# Have historians responded to Raju's critique?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, euclidean-geometry, math-history

[C. K. Raju](http://www.vikasinterventions.in/c-k-raju-abstract) has made some outrageous criticisms of the traditional take on Euclid in particular and Western history in general. Yet he has a book published on the subject with an apparently respectable publisher in India. Have modern historians of the classical period responded to his critique?

Note. One of the responders mentioned a helpful review by Ferreiros [here](https://philmat.oxfordjournals.org/content/17/3/378.extract).

Comment: Aren't they all dead now?

Comment: I am referring to the modern historians who are studying the classical history.

Comment: Have these views been published in refereed history of science journals?

Comment: He has a book published in India. I hasten to add that I do not endorse his views (-4 ??). See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/243126 for a bit more information.

Comment: Maybe you can see: José Ferreirós' review of C.K. RAJU, *Cultural Foundations of Mathematics: The Nature of Mathematical Proof and the Transmission of the Calculus from India to Europe in the 16th c. CE*, in [Philosophia Mathematica Volume 17, Issue 3](https://philmat.oxfordjournals.org/content/17/3/378.extract).

Comment: @Mauro, would you care to format this as an *answer*? Also you could give some snippets from the review in *Philosophia Mathematica*.

Comment: Well, unlike Raju it must be checked *in favor* of facts :-)

Comment: I deeply regret spending half an hour reading Mr Raju's articles. I can only imagine how an historian would feel.

Comment: @Hoot, Ferreiros wrote a reasonably balanced review that I wasn't aware of when I posted this question. See link provided by Mauro above.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I think you should be able to format your *comments* and expand them as an *answer*.

Comment: That link is just a febrile rant, worthy of the worst kind of Social Justice warrior. How can anybody take it seriously?

Comment: This attitude is quite common in India (especially people who have not done serious study of science and mathematics have this view). And most such works or expositions on the superiority of Indians over Europeans in terms of mathematical achievements do not mention anything about Ramanujan. The absence of Ramanujan is a sure shot way to know that author is biased and his purpose is not presenting the truth. I have also seen similar theme in books from Mir Publishers (about Russians).

Comment: I suppose Raju & Co. feel that Ramanujan was a collaborator :-) Still, what puzzles me is not the individual position of C. K. Raju himself but rather the fact that his book is published (and therefore endorsed) by what seems to be a national publisher. @ParamanandSingh

Comment: @MikhailKatz: I really don't know how publishing business works here but perhaps there is lot of influence needed to get things done.

Comment: Speaking as someone of Indian ethnicity, many Indians have this delusion that all of the great discoveries of mathematics and science happened in India. There is naturally an anti-European, anti-Western flavour to these sentiments. This is natural, of course; it's historical revisionism motivated by nationalism, which happens in many cultures. But this peculiar obsession with mathematics is unique to Indians.

Comment: Not to downplay Indian discoveries in math, of course, but they pale in comparison to what Europe, Russia, perhaps even China, have accomplished

Comment: @ParamanandSingh CK Raju has a PHD from ISI Delhi i think, so perhaps he knows something. Science and all are controlled by those who have power & money. There ample evidences where data have been manipulated by scientists to suit their agenda. Medical science is the best example. There were times when doctors were advertising cigarettes during 1960s. Look up.  Each person has his/her own agenda. I basically take a neutral stand and don't trust anything.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh To know more about agenda in institutions like TIFR/ISI which are just puppets in the hands of the west kindly read this article:  http://ckraju.net/papers/Kosambi-the-mathematician.pdf This is about a mathematician DD Kosambi. And if it's hard to digest what Raju has to say, read Goro Shimura's biography the **Map of my life**. He has a enlisted a of controversies there also.

Comment: @MikhailKatz : Prof. Raju has written about this reviewer in detail. Please see : http://ckraju.net/blog/?p=158

Comment: @ParamanandSingh : Those who have studied Math history without any bias would definitely feel proud. It is unfair to say that Indians who have no knowledge of math and science do this without any knowledge. David Mumford has heaped praises on achievements of Indian mathematics and has even went on to say "greek mathematics shouldn't be only seen as mathematics". Please read his review of the book **MATHEMATICS IN INDIA** by Kim Plofker here: https://www.ams.org/notices/201003/rtx100300385p.pdf

Comment: I don't get the point of your comments on this old thread @C.S. Maybe you can discuss the topic on hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Bhai, thanks for responding. Not interested to discuss. Quite boring to keep writing and discussing. However, i felt responding to your earlier comment thats all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can see:

- José Ferreirós' review of C.K. Raju, *Cultural Foundations of Mathematics: The Nature of Mathematical Proof and the Transmission of the Calculus from India to Europe in the 16th c. CE*, in [Philosophia Mathematica Volume 17, Issue 3](https://philmat.oxfordjournals.org/content/17/3/378.extract):

> In his interest to revise traditional historiography and oppose proofcentred mathematics, Raju devotes a lot of effort to questioning the existence
>   of Euclid and insisting that the text of the *Elements* originates at the
>   earliest in 370 CE (with Theon) or perhaps even in the tenth century. In
>   my opinion, this is useless and does not help advance the author’s main theses. For historical purposes, what is relevant is that *Elements* represents
>   a systematisation of a large portion of geometrical knowledge in the Greekspeaking world before the common era. (‘Euclid’ is simply the name of
>   its otherwise unknown author, whose dates—it is true—are dubious; incidentally,
>   an interesting question would be whether philologists find reason
>   to think that the text of *Elements* was written by different authors.) Raju
>   insists on the idea that Proclus’s views represent the original philosophy
>   of mathematics in the *Elements* (p. 25), and he overemphasizes the connections
>   between geometrical proof, Platonism, and Christian religion.

---

Regarding specifically the possibility that Euclid "the man" was a forgery is totally irrelevant: we know quite nothing about him, but we have "the book": *Elements*, and its value does not change if it was written by someone else (but in any case by some ancient Greek: we have testimonies...).

If the *Elements* has been "falsified", this fact does not change of a *iota* the meaning of its content: the theorems. It is not the same thing as saying that the *Holy Bible* has not been written by some ancient prophets and in reality is a late Hellenistic forgery.

Regarding in general the approach to *history* (and *history of science* as well), my humble opinion is that history is like any other science: conjectures and hypotheses are fundamental, and new insight and a fresh point of view can be useful and necessary, but there is a golden rule: all must be checked with facts.

Comment: Prof. Raju has written about this in detail Please read : http://ckraju.net/blog/?p=158

Answer (score 3):

The articles by Raju have a conspirational flavor. The history of Indian mathematics is still an uncharted territory. There are more informative unbiased articles, for instance, there are much deeper and less biased studies I've read:

A. Seidenberg, “The Origin of Mathematics,” Archive for History of Exact Sciences 18, 301-342 (1978).

S.C.Kak, “Science in Ancient India,” in  Ananya:
A Portrait of India, Ed. by S.R.Sridhar and N.K.Matto
(AIA, New York, 1997), pp. 399–420.

Comment: Do you mean to say that what Raju is proposing is a *conspiracy theory*? If so it may be clearer if put that way.

Answer (score -2):

Euclid is no myth.Applonius of Perga directly refers to him in one of his books on conic sections ( In book 3, an original version of which has survived,in Greek).
I have written an article titled'C.K.Rajus mistake' which is on the net exposing all his false arguments.You can read it.I have introduced a lot of new arguments favouring , an Indian origin to Mathematics, and in the course have introduced some Indian philosophical thoughts,which have influenced greek mathematicians starting from Pythogoras.Independent of whether one agrees to my theory,nevertheless, I have busted Raju's false arguments of Euclid being a myth and many of his arguments against Mathematics(which he calls as formal Mathematics).
My paper was published in the 'Mathematics Teacher', the official publication of the society of Mathematics Teachers of India,located in Chennai,India.
The name of the article is 'Stop the Tirade against Euclid.Why Euclid should be more emphasized in Schools than is currently done'I changed its title to'C.K.Rajus mistake' while posting it on the net,to catch the attention of people who may be following him.
Here is the link to the article.
http://www.vixra.org/abs/1504.0198.
Regards.

Comment: That's interesting. Can you provide a link to your paper?  Is it published?